# Dynamically passing gps coordinates to Places API

Tags: geolocation, gps, google-places-api, google-places

I want to pass the current GPS location coordinates  dynamically to Google Places API's location as  parameters, but its not working. The location field in Google Places API request accepts only 'latitude,longitude' as numerical values e.g.'12.12115,17.6626', as written my code can only take static values.

Code:

```
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json', {
    params: {
        location:'19.0321692,73.0603878',
        radius:'500',
        key:''
        }
})
```

This code works with default, static-typed coordinates, but when I store coordinates into 2 variables L1, L2 or 1 variable 'pos' and pass this to the location, it wont work.

Code:

```
var pos = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json', {
    params: {
        location:'pas',//or location:pas;
        radius:'500',
        key:''
    }
})
```

Comment: Two items: 1) Is your code meant to have `pas` instead of `pos`, or is that a typo? 2) When you dynamically pass in a variable, it is not necessary to place it in string format as JS will ignore it's assigned value and instead pass it in as a literal string and not a dynamic insertion. Why don't you go ahead and try that, let us know what happens.

Comment: 1)pas is just a variable in which i'll be storing latitude and longitude 2)i didnt passed coordinates as string , instead i want to dynamically insert the coordinates into location field. And yeah if pass numeric values directly into location field like  for eg location:'13.151126,18.26221' it works , but these will be static .